# How do I remove spaces from search input so that it matches an API tag (one which has no spaces)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, spacing

```
var $hashSearch = $('#hash-search');
var $text = $('#hashtag');
var $results = $('#results');
var $hashTemp = _.template($('#hash-template').html());

$hashSearch.on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('submitted form')

var searchHash = $text.val(); //strip spacing from search


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + searchHash + '/media/recent?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){
        var getImageArray = (data.data[0].images.low_resolution.url)
        var getCapArray = (data.data[0].tags.text)
        _.each(data.data, function(obj){
            var image = (obj.images.low_resolution.url);
            var text = (obj.caption.text);
            var list = new HashList( image, text);
            console.log(image, text);

            list.save();

            list.render();
        });
        }
    });
});
```

I am using Instagram's APIs for my project. On my home page, a user types something in and, when submitted, displays a list of photos pertaining to what was searched. If a user types a value in WITH spaces, an error occurs because the tags are all listed WITHOUT spaces. Is there any way to iterate through each search to filter and remove spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to remove spaces when you assign the input value to `searchHash`

```
var searchHash = $text.val().replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex :

```
 var searchHash = $text.val();
 searchHash = searchHash.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

\s is the regex for "whitespace", and g is the "global" flag, meaning match ALL \s (whitespaces).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove space from search term then you have to add following code just above ajax :

```
searchHash = searchHash.replace(/ /g,"");
```

It will replace the space from string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for multiple tags, try this to see if it works (I can't test this for obvious reasons):

1. Replace spaces with the HTML code for the space, as this will cause your HTTPS request NOT to break to begin with:  `var searchHash = $text.val().replace(/\s/g, '%20');`
2. Use a slightly different API call:  `url:'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=' + searchHash + '/media/recent?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',`

This should result in queries that look like:  `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=fireworks%20explosions%20and%20grand%20finales/media/recent?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Good luck!